# TSQL list horizonal rows vertically

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to list rows vertically grouped by a header field. I have a sample table below. I have looked at pivot but not sure how the would work if I could have a unknown (1-100) number of PkgId under one Cam_Id.

I need it to look like.  Sorry for the jpeg but I don't know how to put a table in here.

```
CamID Pkgid Pkgid PkgId Pkgid Pkgid PkgId Pkgid Pkgid PkgId.....
```

[image]

Comment: When you edit the question, write data in proper columns. Highlight and click `{}`.

Comment: You can use [ASCII table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) or use column name and column values enclosed in pipes (|) and separate column names (first row) from table rows by dash (-): this will format table for you in readable format.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use `string_agg()` and put the results in a single, delimited column:

```
select cam_id,
       string_agg(pkgid, ',') within group (order by pkgid) as pkgids
from t
group by cam_id;
```

If you really want to pivot into separate columns, you can use a construct like this:

```
select cam_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then pkgid end) as pkgid_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then pkgid end) as pkgid_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then pkgid end) as pkgid_3,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cam_id order by pkgid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by cam_id;
```

However, you need to know the maximum number.  Or you can use dynamic SQL to construct a statement with the right number of columns.